# Vim syntax highlighting of doxygen style docstrings in Python

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting, doxygen

I started working with **doxygen** to generate the documentation of my Python code.
I use `doxypy` filter to preprocess the Python docstrings.
My goal is to have a nice syntax highlighting of doxygen comments in Python.

When writing my *mainpage* in a dedicated .dox file, I found that the doxygen comments can be highlighted in **vim** with the following command:

```
set syntax=c.doxygen
```

I tried the same command for Python but I got nothing:
    set syntax=python.doxygen

I also made some googling and couldn't find anything interesting

Here is a typical piece of code I'd like to highlight:

```
class CompilationTab:
    """
    The compilation tab of the verif GUI. It contains the layout description
    and the functions required to deal with specific behaviors of the tab
    """
    def __init__(self, notebook, tab_name):
        """
        The class constructor.

        @param notebook Notebook: The parent @c Notebook widget
        @param tab_name String: The display name of the tab
        """
```

Does anybody already fixed this issue?
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into `syntax/doxygen.vim` you can read in the preamble of the file that currently only

```
cpp, c, idl, doxygen and php
```

files are supported.

Since `doxygen.vim` works a lot with the `syn region` command i searched for the line that defines the multiline string in `syntax/python.vim`.

The interesting part of the command that defines this region is

```
syn region pythonString start=+[uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend
```

Derived from that what is in `doxygen.vim` and the above line you can add the following lines

```
"delete the following line if you don't want to have enhanced colors
let g:doxygen_enhanced_color=1
runtime! syntax/doxygen.vim
syn region doxygenComment matchgroup=pythonString start=+[uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" contains=doxygenSyncStart,doxygenStart,doxygenTODO keepend fold containedin=pythonString
```

to `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` or execute them by hand.

In addition you may have to customize the colors of the added doxygen highlighting groups by hand. At least i would do so since the resulting look doesn't conform with my taste.

Perhaps the `fold` argument of the `syn` command is of special interest for you. If you set `foldmethod` to `syntax` you can fold and unfold the multiline comments. That seems to be useful if you could no longer stand the view of those colors and are to lazy to adjust them :)

---

without doxygen highlighting:

[image]

with doxygen highlighting and `g:doxygen_enhanced_color == 1`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works just fine :)! I have an issue when using a ftplugin/python.vim. The syntax is not loaded, even if I have `filetype plugin on` and that `:filetype` gives my `python`. I temporarily solved it by adding the 3 lines you gave me in the syntax/python.vim. I fear that my setup is little bit buggy.

Comment: Btw, as you said the highlighting is not perfect. I may try to update it later on...

Comment: Indeed adding the commands to `ftplugin/python.vim` doesn't work. You should put them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` instead. I will correct that in my answer. Best regards

Comment: Thank you for the update. Indeed it works correctly inside `after/syntax` directory.

Comment: For those that got here, tried it and found that this changes their python syntax highlighting: there is a pythonAttribute syn match in the shipped highlighting and it has a contains=ALLBUT which will pull in the doxygen definitions. using "syn clear pythonAttribute" and then copying the exisintg and replacing ALLBUT with TOP should fix that