# Highlighting ReST in python doc strings within vim

Tags: python, vim, syntax, highlight, restructuredtext

Since I am using Sphinx with autodoc I would like to have my vim highlight python docstrings with ReST syntax. Is that possible?

Searching with google yielded only one usable result (I was surprised not to find more though):
http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~labbe/blogue/2011/06/rest-syntax-highlighting-for-sage-docstrings-in-vim/
But this solution seems to have some circular dependency which causes my vim to complain with infinite error messages... dunno how to solve that :/

On Stackoverflow I found this one:
[Vim syntax highlighting of doxygen style docstrings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120713/vim-syntax-highlighting-of-doxygen-style-docstrings-in-python)
But I have no idea how to adapt that either.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Finally I found the plugin [riv.vim](https://github.com/Rykka/riv.vim) with `let g:riv_python_rst_hl=1` it does what I want.

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer

Comment: I tried, answers which are too short are automatically transformed to comments...

Comment: Fill it out a bit? describe what riv.vim is, and what that options does, and what flaws it has...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a vim plugin [riv.vim](https://github.com/gu-fan/riv.vim) that provides lots of tools for interacting with reST documents. If you do:

```
let g:riv_python_rst_hl=1
```

It will enable proper reST syntax hilighting for docstrings in python files.

Comment: This plugin doesn't work for me. The docstrings in my python files are unchanged.